# Symfony2 make mandatory to be logged in to post a blog and comments

Tags: security, symfony, doctrine

I am struggling to implement a functionality on my website to ensure that a user must be logged in, in order to publish a post or a comment. How can I define it? I am using the newest symfony 2.6.

Comment: [URL patterns](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-url-patterns-access-control) or [@annotations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html) are the good ways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define if a url is public or not in your app/config/config.yml

```
security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/path/public/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }
        - { path: ^/path/secure/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```